# Reading large txt file async and reporting progress in progressbar WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, progress-bar, reporting

I am trying to read a large txt file (>50MB) asynchronously and while it is being read, report the progress on the UI progressbar and have the option to cancel the process. So far I have read and processed the file async as I wanted but I could not solve the progressbar part.

```
public static async Task<string> ReadTxtAsync(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var reader = File.OpenText(filePath))
            {
                var content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                return content;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }

        
 public static async Task<Dictionary<string, int>> OpenTxtAsync()
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> uniqueWords = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Text Documents (*.txt)|*.txt";
        string content = null;
        try
        {
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                string filePath = openFileDialog.FileName.ToString();

                if (openFileDialog.CheckFileExists && new[] { ".txt" }.Contains(Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToLower()) && filePath != null)
                {
                    Task<string> readText = ReadTxtAsync(filePath);
                    content = await readText;
                    uniqueWords = WordExtractor.CountWords(ref content);
                }
                else MessageBox.Show("Please use .txt format extension!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return uniqueWords;
    }

private async void LoadFileButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task<Dictionary<string, int>> dictionaryContent = TextFileLoader.OpenTxtAsync();
        uniqueWords = await dictionaryContent;
        UpdateListView();
    }
```

How can I check where `ReadToEndAsync()` is currently? How can I get it to continously update the progressbar and how can I cancel it?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @emoacht I managed to get the progressbar to update correctly and display its percentage. The only thing that remains is to cancel the task, which I tried according to a Tim Corey video, but it did not work on my code.

```
        public static async Task<string> ReadTextAsync(string filePath, IProgress<(double current, double total)> progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        var readTask = reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        var progressTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (stream.Position < stream.Length)
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
                progress.Report((stream.Position, stream.Length));
            }
        });

        await Task.WhenAll(readTask, progressTask);
        return readTask.Result;
    }

                        try
                    {
                        Task<string> readText = TextFileLoader.ReadTextAsync(filePath, progress, cts.Token);
                        content = await readText;
                        LabelProgress.Content = "Done Reading! Now creating wordlist...";
                    }
                    catch (OperationCanceledException)
                    {

                        LabelProgress.Content = "File laden wurde abgebrochen";
                    }
```

I have a buttonClick Event for cancel `cts.Cancel();` but the only part where it works is the Dictionary creation. If I place the `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` into the progressbar update part, it stops only the update, the stream reading still continues. If I place is right below `var readTask = reader.ReadToEndAsync();` it does nothing.

Comment: What medium are you reading from?
From a modern HDD (I don't even write about SSD), reading a 50 Mb ReadToEndAsync file will take less than a second.
You won't even have time to see any progress.

Comment: You can use `StringBuilder` and read file line by line, `ReadToEndAsync` is atomic you cannot track it's progress.

Comment: @EldHasp I have written 50MB as an example, currently I test it with 150-300MB. I know it does not require that much time (especially with SSD) but the assignment states it has to remain responsive and has to have a progressbar, regardless of file size.

Comment: The question was wrongly closed, none of the mentioned duplicates have anything to do with async file reading, which is my main concern here, and my question regarding the cancellation of the ReadToEndAsync method still stands.

Comment: @Nyariszalami You can find a number of samples to implement cancellation to read method. It's up to you.

Comment: @emoacht Yeah I already solved the cancellation in the meantime. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current position while reading by checking `Stream.Position` property at regular interval. The following method will check the current position once per 100 milliseconds and report it by `current` value of `progress` parameter. To use this method, instantiate Progess<(double current, double total)> and subscribe to its `ProgressChanged` event.

```
public static async Task<string> ReadTextAsync(string filePath, IProgress<(double current, double total)> progress)
{
    using var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

    var readTask = reader.ReadToEndAsync();

    var progressTask = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (stream.Position < stream.Length)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
            progress.Report((stream.Position, stream.Length));
        }
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(readTask, progressTask);

    return readTask.Result;
}
```